# Need a mutable vector inside a struct

Tags: rust

I need to have a mutable vector for containing references to other objects inside of a struct. Rust is complaining that I can't use 'let' inside of structs, but I still haven't found a way listed in the online Rust Book that makes the compiler happy.

The Meta-Object Protocol struct needs to have a private container to store the addresses of other objects for its operation. Is there a way in Rust for this to be done?

```
pub struct MetaObjectProtocol {
    // Metaobject Registry
    // Container holding references to all existing Metaobjects
    let mut mop_registry = Vec<MetaObject>;
}
```

Comment: It seems like the request does one thing and the code tries to do another so I have a couple of clarifying questions: (1) you want a vector of *references* (which creates lifetime issues), but you create a vector of objects. (2) you specifically call out mop_registry being mutable - if you have a `&mut MetaObjectProtocol` you have the right to mutate its fields already. Or do you need this vector to be mutable, *even if you only have an immutable reference* to `MetaObjectProtocol`?

Comment: To the first point (since I'm about to overflow the limit for comment length): do you specifically need this to be a vector of references? or can it be a vector of owned objects, Arcs, anything else that avoids lifetime-related complexities when using your MetaObjectProtocol?

Comment: @nanofarad I took out the '&' from the type specification when I was trying different ways to get it to work. As for the vector: yes, it needs to be mutable so references can be added/removed as the objects they point to are added/removed. 

I just tried changing things to:   let &mut mop_registry = Vec<&MetaObject>;
and it still screams at me. Please let me know if you have a way to get this to work.

Comment: It's a vector storing pointers (references) to other objects to help keep track of them. I'm new to Rust so I have no idea what you mean when you mention Arcs. 

My understanding of Rust is that everything is immutable until specified otherwise.

If you have a solution that works, please post it.

Comment: @nanofarad Please consider reframing your comments as specific requests for clarifying [edit]s to the question. You've written a large amount of maybe-answer, but [that's not what comments are for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KevinReid Given the now-available answer (which I've upvoted as I believe it answers the question as clarified) and the non-constructive accusation by the OP of "trolling" in a comment on the answer, I'd rather just delete them and go to bed. While they could have been written more coherently as brief clarification requests (and they were IMO quite germane to the question at hand and its multiple points), I was confused enough by the question that it merited clarifying what I was actually trying to get clarification on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to have a mutable vector for containing references to other objects inside of a struct.

Ignoring the “references” part for the moment: then you want a *field* of the struct. Fields are declared with their name and type; no `let`. This code will compile:

```rust
pub struct MetaObjectProtocol {
    /// Metaobject Registry
    mop_registry: Vec<MetaObject>,
}
```

(All fields are private by default.) Now, as to the rest of the problem: you also mentioned in a comment:

> My understanding of Rust is that everything is immutable until specified otherwise.

This is incorrect. Everything is *uniquely owned* unless otherwise specified. Its owner gets to mutate it, and **nobody else gets to access it at all.** (`let mut` for variables is a bit of an odd case, because without the `mut` you get ownership but *not* mutability; but that never affects types and function signatures — so you can always add `mut` to a `let` without changing the meaning of the rest of the program.)

So, the above declaration is appropriate if `MetaObject`s are to be owned by the `MetaObjectProtocol`. But you say “references to”, and you probably don't want Rust `&` references, because those *prohibit mutations while they exist*, and they come with *lifetimes* which can be quite restrictive in order to arrange them properly.

If you want to *share access to* the `MetaObject` between this registry and other owners, then you probably need to use [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) (or `Rc`, its single-thread-only relative). However, that's a considerably more complex topic, and it wouldn't be fitting to write an entire tutorial here; I encourage you to read, or continue reading, [“the Rust Book”](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/title-page.html) until you get to [the chapter on `Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-04-rc.html). The preceding chapters will cover many things you need to know to successfully write a complex Rust program, and put `Rc` and `Arc` into context.